# Why method executes slow?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

There is a JSON file on server, which contain four "key/value" pairs about version of data in app (it is a cook book, so the version is a version of recipes)
When application starts, it download JSON and check version.

Here is my method, but I think it is very slow.

```
- (void)isUpdatesAvail
{
   updatesAvail = NO;

   NSInteger iVer = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ingredientsVer"];
   NSInteger rVer = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"recipesVer"];
   NSInteger iCnt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ingredientsCount"];
   NSInteger rCnt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"recipesCount"];

   NSString *countPath = [downloadPath stringByAppendingString:@"/versioninfo"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:countPath]];
   NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
   NSError *error = nil;
   if (!responseData) {
       return;
   }
   NSDictionary *recipesCount = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
   if (!recipesCount) {
      return;
   }

   rCount = [recipesCount objectForKey:@"recipeCount"];
   iCount = [recipesCount objectForKey:@"ingredientCount"];
   rVersion = [recipesCount objectForKey:@"recipeVersion"];
   iVersion = [recipesCount objectForKey:@"ingredientVersion"];

   if ([iVersion integerValue] > iVer || [rVersion integerValue] > rVer || [iCount integerValue] > iCnt || [rCount integerValue] > rCnt) {
       updatesAvail = YES;
   }
}
```

Can somebody give me advice (or may be example) how to do that?

Comment: Your time will be dominated by the server request.  You should avoid synchronous requests which will block main thread (unless this is done on bg thread)

Answer (score 0):

It's 'slow' because it performs a synchronous URL request. It's probably just waiting for the network transfer to complete for most of the time it executes if it is noticeably slow.

There's not much you can do to make it faster, apart from either caching the data or reducing the size of the data.

In any event, you should just perform an asynchronous request then do your work/update after it's completed.